# How can I center (align) an image in a question?

Tags: support, formatting

I have not found this and I'm not sure it's possible, but when I write a question or answer and want an image to be horizontally centred, how would I do that?

Comment: [Either use `<pre>` or `&nbsp;`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites).